# Show $\Bigl\{\sqrt{2\over {\pi}}\sin (nx)\Bigr\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is an orthogonal basis of $L_2[0,\pi]$

Tags: vector-spaces, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Show $\Bigl\{\sqrt{2\over {\pi}}\sin (nx)\Bigr\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is an orthogonal basis of $L_2[0,\pi]$. What I need is a verification and guidance. I managed to show that the set is orthogonal. My attempt is:

Let us take $f\in L_2[0,\pi]$ with $\langle f(x),\sin (nx)\rangle = 0$ for all $n$. Let us look at $L_2[-\pi,\pi]$ and define:

$$g(x)=\begin{cases}
f(x),  & \text{if $0\le x\le\pi$} \\
-f(x), & \text{$-\pi\le x<0$}
\end{cases}.$$

$g(x)$ is continuous and satisfies $g(x)=g(-x)$. Furthermore, $\langle g(x),\sin(nx)\rangle = 0$ for all $n$. Since be Fourier Analysis one can arrive at: $g(x)={a_0\over 2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n\cos (nx)+b_n\sin(nx))$ where $a_n={1\over \sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{g(x)\cos(nx)}dx$ and $b_n={1\over \sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{g(x)\sin(nx)}dx$. Since $g(x)$ is even, $b_n=0$. Here, I am a little confused. What can I do with this ${a_0\over 2}$? Setting $x={\pi\over 2}$, $g(x)={a_0\over 2}$, $\langle g({\pi\over 2}),\sin({\pi\over 2})\rangle = 0$ which means ${a_0\over 2}=0$. Is that legitimate? Now I have that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \langle \cos(kx),\sin(nx)\rangle = 0$ but $\cos (nx)$ is even and therefore $\langle \cos (mx),\sin(nx)\rangle = 0$ for all $n,m\ge 1$. Therefore $g(x)\equiv0$ and in particular $g(x)=0$ in $L_2[0,1]$ which means the set is complete and thus a basis. What I am not sure about is the Fourier analysis parts and the transition between the two spaces. I could really use your help. If it is true, couldn't one show $\cos(nx)$ have the same property? It sounds too coincidental, as if from any $L_2[a,b]$ set one could derive the same with few manipulations. Is there a basis behind that logic?

Comment: Your statement is simply false ; every vector in your base is orthogonal to the function $f_0=1$, or to $f_n= cos(nx)$. What is true is that your set in a samily of orthogonal vectors of length $1$.

Comment: I didn't quite understand you. How, then, am I expected to show that the base vectors are orthogonal if they aren't?

Comment: But $<\sin(mx),\sin(nx)>=0$ after integration. Why is there no orthogonality?

Comment: I get $\int \sin (mx) \sin(nx)={1\over 2}(\int \cos((m-n)x)-\int \cos((m+n)x))={1\over 2}({\sin((m-n))\over m-n}-{\sin((m+n))\over m+n})$ which is zero at $\pi k$ and hence by any combination such as ${1\over 2}({\sin((m-n))\over m-n}-{\sin((m+n))\over m+n})|_{0}^{\pi}$. Where is the false part here?

Comment: ok it's my mistake, you are right, thanks

Comment: Sorry, in fact every function of $L^2[0,\pi]$ can be extended in a function on $\bf L^2 [-\pi, \pi]$ by $F(t)=1\sqrt 2 f(t)$ if $t>0$ $F(t)=-1\sqrt 2 f(-t)$ if not. This isometrically embedd the first space into the second. The image of this operator $A(f)=F$ is exactly the family of odd functions (in the a.e. sense), whence your result...

Comment: Meitar's work is totally sound and accurate and can be found in texts.You can indeed do  the same kind of thing with cosines.

Comment: You can find the proof of your problem in the book Functional analysis. An introduction by  Y. Eidelman, V. Milman and A. Tsolomitis, in the section solutions to the exersies of chapter 2 (problem 17). The completenes of the system $\{1,\sin nx,\cos nx\}$ in the space $L^2[-\pi,\pi]$ is used there.

Answer (score 2):

Well, no answer has been given, so here's one:

We know $\{\cos nx:n=0,1,\dots \}\cup \{\sin nx:n=1,2,\dots \}$ is an orthogonal basis of $L^2[-\pi,\pi].$ Suppose $g\in L^2[-\pi,\pi]$ is odd. Then

$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi g(x)\cos nx\, dx = 0, n=0,1,\dots $$

Thus such a $g$ can be written uniquely as

$$ \tag 1 g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n \sin nx,$$

the sum converging in $L^2[-\pi,\pi].$

Now to your question: You've shown $\{\sin nx:n=1,2,\dots \}$ is orthogonal in $L^2[0,\pi].$ Suppose $f\in L^2[0,\pi].$ Extend $f$ to an odd function $g$ on $[-\pi,\pi].$ Then $g$ has an expansion as in $(1).$ So

$$\int_0^\pi |f(x) - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n \sin nx|^2 \, dx =\int_{0}^\pi |g(x) - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n \sin nx|^2\, dx$$ $$\le \int_{-\pi}^\pi |g(x) - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n \sin nx|^2\, dx =0.$$

This shows $\{\sin nx:n=1,2,\dots \}$ is an orthogonal basis of $L^2[0,\pi]$ as desired.